# How can I get a UK transit visa when my US student visa has expired?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, transit-visas

I'm in US on a student visa, currently expired; my last entry was 3 years ago. I 
do have an approved I-797 (H1-B). Can I travel through London without a transit visa? BTW, the layover is 3 hours and I don't need to change the terminal.

I tried applying for transit visa on [UK Embassy portal](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk) but, with my expired student visa on my passport, it doesn't let me go to next step.

Since I can't transit without visa and I need a visa for the UK connection, what should I do?

Comment: Did you most recently enter the US less than six months before your anticipated transit?

Comment: No, it's been 3 years since my last US entry

Comment: Sorry to close your question, but the conditions allowing transit without visa (both direct airside transit and "landside" transit) are listed at the duplicate question, and you do not seem to meet any of them.  Your problem, therefore, is whether you can apply for a DATV in the US and, if so, how.  Perhaps you could ask a new question about that.  This is of course if you do not have a nationality that allows visa-free entry to the UK, but I assume you've already taken that into account and determined that you do not.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't find answers in any of the posts you mentioned. See ,y question, I asked also for "I tried applying for transit visa on UK embassy portal, but with my expired student visa on my passport, it doesn't let me go to next step."

Comment: I wish I could post a picture, it doesn't let me here

Comment: "I tried applying for transit visa on UK embassy portal, but with my expired student visa on my passport, it doesn't let me go to next step" isn't a question actually, but if you want to edit this question to ask about that, we can reopen it.  I think it would be simpler to post a new question, however. Which site are you using that doesn't allow you to proceed with an expired visa?

Comment: This :https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk

Comment: I reopened.  I would edit the body to make it more explicitly a question about how to get the visa, with perhaps a statement that you need one, rather than asking whether you can qualify for transit without visa with the I-797 (which you can't).

Comment: You can post a picture in your question now. Use the image button to upload images.

Comment: What step are you stuck on?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify putting on hold